# How to identify user when trying to send data via socket

Tags: node.js, laravel, api, sockets, electron

On my `electron` app I have a `web-socket` connection which gets all needed data from `laravel api`. So every user need to get own data,but I can not identify user on sending data from `api`. Please help to identify user. My `api` based on `laravel` , and socket on `Nodejs`

Comment: Users need to login? After login establish some sort of session with the user... You can do this by send the user a token that each subsequent api call will use to authenticate... I don't know how secure your app must be but there are many ways to do this...

Comment: Hi @Serge. First I am running an artisan command (every second) to check all changes. After getting all updates I need to send to users all own updates. So I can not understand how can I implement identifying users by session

Comment: Typically, a user must first establish the connection with the back end to identify himself and establish a session. From this point, you have a chance to identify who is at the end of that connection... So when your electron app starts, you display a login screen that identifies the user. Once verified, the user receives a token that ideitifies him... then every request, that user sends the token with the request which lets you know who the request is for thus send that user the appropriate data... You could also send this token by email to users and then enter it somewhere in the app...

Comment: @Serge please take a look at my ticket on `laracast.com` and let me know how can I do that. Thank you very much.
`https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-identify-user-when-sending-a-data-via-socket`